# Cast strings to Integers and compare

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to get the file size in MB of a directory and do different things for different sizes of the directory. My code is:

```
file_size_with_path=$(du -sb $file_path)
file_size=$(echo "$file_size_with_path" | tr -d -c 0-9)
echo "$file_size"
## if directory size is betweem 1GB and 10 GB:
if [[ ($file_size < 10737418240 ) && ($file_size > 1073741824 ) ]]; then   
    echo "yoyo1"
    block_size=$(($file_size/120))
    block_size_in_bytes=$(($block_size*1024))
    stripe_size_in_bytes=$((block_size_in_bytes/4))
## if directory size is greater than 10 GB
elif [[ ($file_size > 10737418240 ) ]] ; then
    echo "yoyo2"
    block_size_in_bytes="67108864"
    stripe_size_in_bytes=$((block_size_in_bytes/4))
##if directory size is less than 1 GB
elif [[ ($file_size < 1073741824 ) ]] ; then
    echo "yoyo3"
    block_size_in_bytes="16777216"
    stripe_size_in_bytes=$((block_size_in_bytes/4))
fi
```

The code when executed for a directory of size 3318222 goes into the second elif block (i.e. prints yoyo2) but it shoudl have gone into the third one and printed yoyo3. Someone please suggest how to cast the strings as integers and do a comparison.

I tried to put double quotes around the variables and the numbers but did not work. I looked at other answers but am afraid nothing worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `bash` here.

Rather than

```
if [[ ($file_size < 10737418240 ) && ($file_size > 1073741824 ) ]]
```

you may use

```
if (( file_size < 10737418240 )) && (( file_size > 1073741824 ))
```

The `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic evaluation in which variable names will be interpreted as integers and the operators `<`, `>` etc. acts as the usually do on integers.

With

```
[[ $file_size < 10737418240 ]]
```

you're comparing two strings in the sorting order of the current locale (according to `$LC_COLLATE`).

Comment: Variables - not variable names - will be interpreted as integers

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Hmm... that's almost a bit of a philosophical question: What is the difference between a variable and its name? My point was that one leaves the `$` out.

Answer (score 2):

When using `bash` tests within `[[` `]]` pairs, use `-gt` and `-lt` for numeric 'greater-than' and 'less-than' comparisons. `<` and `>` are used for string comparisons, in which `[[ 1000000 < 90 ]]` would indeed be true.